# How to set default value to dropdown in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I want to give a default value (`final province`) to dropdown.
but i don't know how to do that.

```
class ChooseAddress extends StatefulWidget {
  final province;
  const ChooseAddress({Key? key,required this.provincee}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChooseAddressState createState() => _ChooseAddressState();
}

class _ChooseAddressState extends State<ChooseAddress> {

   ProvinceModel? _value;

  Widget Province(double pageHeight, double pageWidth){
    return Container(
      height: 60,
      width: pageWidth,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: pageWidth/20),
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
            menuMaxHeight: pageHeight/2,
            elevation: 2,
            value: _value,
            items: _items.map((item){
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child:  Text(item.name),
                value: item,);
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _value = value as ProvinceModel;
           });
            },
            hint: AutoSizeText(
              "choose province",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: pageWidth / 25),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

note that `final province` can be null so i need to handle it.

also my province model is:

```
class ProvinceModel{
  late String name;
  late int id;
  ProvinceModel(this.name,this.id);
}
```

the `final province` is just the `String name` of ProvinceModel

Comment: *"I want to give a default value"* - assign to `_value` that default value then - now it is `null`

Comment: @pskink i do like this : `value: widget.province ?? _value as ProvinceModel ,` but it doesn't work and shows an error

Answer (score 0):

Override`initState` to initial the value on `_value`.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value = widget.province;
  }
```

More about [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) and [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html#:%7E:text=A%20dropdown%20button%20lets%20the,that%20each%20dropdown%20item%20represents.).